# SOAPHandler for WSSecurity with Digital Signature

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, ws-security

I am trying to create a Soap client in java, where I have to Sign the Soap message using my private key.

I am getting response using `SoapUI`, with `WS-Security` configured.

I have imported the WSDL and generated classes using `wsimport`.

I created a `SOAPHandler` to sign the message like below. I am not sure If this is the correct way to sign the message.

```
@Override
private void handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) throws SOAPException, WSSecurityException {
    try {
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = context.getMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();
        WSSecHeader wsSecHeader = new WSSecHeader();
        wsSecHeader.setMustUnderstand(true);
        wsSecHeader.insertSecurityHeader(soapPart);

        WSSecTimestamp wsSecTimeStamp = new WSSecTimestamp();
        wsSecTimeStamp.prepare(soapPart);
        wsSecTimeStamp.prependToHeader(wsSecHeader);

        WSSConfig wssConfig = new WSSConfig();
        WSSecSignature sign = new WSSecSignature(wssConfig);
        sign.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.BST_DIRECT_REFERENCE);

        Properties cxfProps = new Properties();
        cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
        cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "jks");
        cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias", "example.com");
        cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", "password");
        cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file", "keystore.jks");

        Crypto crypto1 = CryptoFactory.getInstance(cxfProps);

        sign.prepare(soapPart, crypto1, wsSecHeader);
        String bstId = sign.getBSTTokenId();
        sign.appendBSTElementToHeader(wsSecHeader);
        sign.setDigestAlgo("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256");
        sign.setSignatureAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
        Vector<WSEncryptionPart> signParts = new Vector<WSEncryptionPart>();
        signParts.add(new WSEncryptionPart(wsSecTimeStamp.getId()));
        signParts.add(new WSEncryptionPart(WSConstants.ELEM_BODY,
                WSConstants.URI_SOAP12_ENV, ""));
        signParts.add(new WSEncryptionPart(bstId));
        sign.addReferencesToSign(signParts, wsSecHeader);
        List<Reference> referenceList = sign.addReferencesToSign(signParts,
                wsSecHeader);
        sign.computeSignature(referenceList, false, null);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SecurityHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.convertAlias(JavaKeyStore.java:57)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetCertificateChain(JavaKeyStore.java:153)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetCertificateChain(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
at java.security.KeyStore.getCertificateChain(KeyStore.java:1036)
at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin.getX509Certificates(Merlin.java:1277)
at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin.getX509Certificates(Merlin.java:600)
at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.getSigningCerts(WSSecSignature.java:793)
at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.prepare(WSSecSignature.java:169)
at app.SecurityHandler.handleOutboundMessage(SecurityHandler.java:187)
```

Comment: any idea about this?

Comment: Used Spring [webservice template](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html) and added configuration using  Wss4jSecurityInterceptor

Answer (score 1):

In order to select target private key from your keystore you have to add

```
sign.setUserInfo("key-alias", "key-password");
```

in your code.